# .htaccess not working for php/mvc in subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Desired goal:**
On an existing website, I need to implement a new website. The new site needs to be 'staged' implementation, so a subdirectory for 'dev' and for 'test' and for 'site' is made. All three subdirectories contain an identical php/mvc implementation except for the fact that different useraccounts and databases are used. The current site which resides in the rootdirectory should be kept working as well.

**Current configuration attempt:**
I have put an .htaccess file in the root directory of the current website.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^/dev(.*)$ <url>/dev/$1
RewriteRule ^/test(.*)$ <url>/test/$1
RewriteRule ^/site(.*)$ <url>/site/$1
```

Note: instead of  there is a complete url.
This should redirect all urls with 'dev' in it, to /dev/$1 and $1 contains all the rest of the parameters.

**Result:**
When the homepage of 'dev' of 'test' or 'site' is called. The homepage shows up perfectly fine.

**Problem:**
Everytime I click on a menu-item or a link, the resulting url gets rewritten to the right url, which is: /dev/volunteering?page=volunteering&lang=nl

but I get an errormessage 404:

```
The requested URL /dev/volunteering was not found on this server.
```

Please keep in mind that it is about a custom mvc implementation.

**Required Help:**
What change is necessary to make the browser understand that this kind of requests should not be handled by the current website but that, depending of 'dev' or 'test' or 'site', the request should be forwarded to the appropriate subdirectory in such way that the mvc implementation understands?

Comment: If you're talking about MVC, then you need a router. **YOU SHOULD NOT** rewrite the rules, but keep a single one. What if you have 20 or 50 rewrites? Are you gonna rewrite them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(dev)(volunteering([^?]*)) $1/$2?page=$2&lang=nl [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(test)(volunteering([^?]*)) $1/$2?page=$2&lang=nl [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(site)(volunteering([^?]*)) $1/$2?page=$2&lang=nl [L,NC]
```

Comment: Does the direct URL: /dev/volunteering?page=volunteering&lang=nl generate any error?

Comment: It generates the following error: The requested URL /dev//volunteering was not found on this server.

Comment: I just noticed the double // in the errormessage, so i removed a / between $1 and $2 but the error is just the same (only with one /)

Comment: I asked whether original URL (without re-writing) /dev/volunteering?page=volunteering&lang=nl works correctly or not. Could you mention the full address with website name if possible?

Comment: At this point, I found out that any request coming from the mvc model is redirected by the rewriterule to the apropriate subdirectory (/dev or /site or /test). Because it is a mvc, the index.php in the subdirectory of eg. /dev has no clue at all of what to do with this file. So I created an .htaccess file in the /dev directory as well. This is how it looks like: 'RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /dev/index.php [NC,L]

Comment: This results in some redirection. At least one menu item works now, but I guess that is a coincidence. First I have to review the $_GET['parameter1','parameter2'] to see if this is correct. I will post results later.

Comment: After some enhancements this appeared to be the final solution. Thanks to everyone who helped!